# Is it possible to make the PlotRegion in graphics as a shape?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a specific pattern to show in `Graphics` and I would like to choose the `PlotRegion` as a shape. In other words, I would like to show part of the pattern within a specific shape such as `Hexagon` or `Polygon`.

Assume that the pattern is `Rectangle`, see below, and I would like to make the `PlotRegion` to be a `Hexagon`. How can I do that?

```
Graphics[{Pink, Rectangle[]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Transparent` as a color and make a mask using it. Combine different `Graphics` with `Show` or combine the lists of graphics primitives.

Note, that this can also be done with continues `Opacity` and not only sharp cutoff. For example `Transparent` can be used in the `ColorFunction` of `DensityPlot` and then your mask can be described by a continues value function.

The mask can be constructed using `RegionDifference`

```
Show[{Graphics[{Pink, Rectangle[]}], 
  DiscretizeRegion[
   RegionDifference[Rectangle[], Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.3]], 
   BaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[White]]]}]
```

[image]

If the underlying graphics you mask is a `Plot`-like and not a general `Graphcis`, one can use `MeshRegion` and `RegionFunction`. See [the related Q&A.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181931/densityplot-with-equal-mesh-and-certain-boundary)

Comment: Can you please put an example even for a circle shape?

Comment: @Abdullah please see the updated example.