# Restricting the domain of a StreamPlot to a non rectangular region

Tags: plotting

First, I should say I am at best an advanced amateur at *Mathematica*, and that generally speaking my knowledge of programming (in any language) is more in computation than visualization.

There is a model I am working on for which I have recently shown there is a feasibility region: $$\mathcal{R} = \{(x,y) \in [0,\infty)\times[0, \infty) : x+y \leq L\}.$$  Of course this is a triangular subregion of the first quadrant.  I wish to restrict the domain of the streamplots I am generating to $\mathcal{R}$.

From looking at the documentation I have constructed the following code:

```
StreamPlot[{dx/dt, dy/dt}, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}]
```

which works fine, but of course gives me a large amount of unneeded data that clutters up my attempted visualization.  So then, my question is:

**How do I restrict the domain of StreamPlot to $\mathcal{R} $**?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.se! Full minimalistic code to demonstrate the issue, please! Then it is much easier for us to help you out!

Comment: Closely related to [DensityPlot with equal mesh and a certain boundary](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181931/2036)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
StreamPlot[{dx/dt, dy/dt}, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x+y <= L]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 2 < x^2 + y^2 < 9]]
```

[image]

or

```
StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, y} \[Element] 
  StadiumShape[{{0, 0}, {2, 3}}, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  This code will be very helpful if I ever need to plot a circular region.

Comment: Just to demonstrate that the solution is not limted to circlar region, I updated the answer with a more compelx shape.

Comment: it's like a fingerprint!